# Disable gzip content-encoding in android simulator

Tags: android, http, android-emulator

I was trying to read the HTTP messages between the browser in the Android simulator and other third party web-servers using `tcpdump`. However, since the browser can accept `gzip` content-encoding, I can't see the HTML content as plain-text in the `tcpdump` output. Is there a way to change the configs of the browser so that it doesn't send that `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This post implies if you remove the

```
Accept-Encoding
```

header, you'll get raw data back... you should be able to write a custom WebView that never sends that header.  Hope that works!

http://forgetmenotes.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-disable-gzip-compression-in.html